# Copy "Template" worksheet to other worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates worksheets based on a data range and it works fine:

```vb
Sub AddSheetsFromCells()
    
    Dim xRg As Range, wBk As Workbook
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    
    On Error GoTo Quit
    Set dbRange = Application.InputBox("Range: ", "Select Range", _
    Application.Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    For Each xRg In dbRange
    With wBk
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    Debug.Print Chr(34) & xRg.Value & Chr(34) & " already used as a sheet name"
    .ActiveSheet.Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Next xRg
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Quit:
    
    End Sub
```

[image: Screen]

Is it possible that these created worksheets contain the same as in the template tab?

[image: Screen2]

Comment: Would you kindly take a moment to apply some indentation of your VBA to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `.Sheets.Add`, try this:

```
.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
```

Let us know if that works